# Chrubuntu on Acer C7: SD card reader only works on AC power?

Tags: sd-card

I have an Acer C7 chromebook on which I have installed Chrubuntu. Everything works great except that the SD card reader doesn't work when the computer is running from battery power. It recognizes the card and works perfectly as soon as I plug it into AC power.

Is there a power management setting somewhere that I need to toggle to be able to use my SD card reader on battery power?

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here.  I noted dmesg gave this line when it wasn't plugged in:

```
mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
```

A search around that term lead me to [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2042450.html) which suggested:

```
sudo rmmod tg3
sudo modprobe tg3
```

Which fixes the issue as soon as you remove the tg3 module.  I also noted that while the reader doesn't work without power or the above fix, it will continue to work if you unplug it while it is mounted.